# Compatibility of ZeroMQ sockets written on different languages

Tags: python, go, zeromq

I've built an app written on python, based on **`ZeroMQ`**, but now I'm facing perfomance issues. So I decided to rewrite some modules of my app using, let's say, Golang. But when I try to establish messaging between sockets, implemented by different languages, anything does not work.
I've searched so far, but I didn't find any info about compatibility problems of `ZeroMQ` using different languages.

**So the question is:** Can I use golang for server implementation based on `ZeroMQ` and client written on python to connect to it?
Or do I have to use only one language?

**EDIT**: here are typical server and client that I'm trying to get working properly

server:

```
import zmqctx = zmq.Context()
sock = ctx.socket(zmq.REP)
sock.bind("tcp://*:57000")
msg = sock.recv()
```

client:

```
package main

import (
    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
)

func main() {

    ctx, _ := zmq.NewContext()
    sock, _ := ctx.NewSocket(zmq.REQ)

    sock.Connect("tcp://localhost:57000")
    sock.Send("simple message", 0)
}
```

Server stucks at `sock.recv()`

Comment: I recently rewritten one of my slow python (celery) modules to Go. It was communicating with re rest of the system via RabbitMQ. I don't know ZeroMQ, but I guess it has a common protocol for all connecting clients, so it should work. Maybe You are doing something wrong? What kind of problems are You experiencing?

Comment: when you say "rewrite in, let's say, Golang" do you mean this is hypethetical or have you actually done the rewrites? I'd recommend writing C extensions for python for performance if you have not already done the rewrites.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, to be honest, I'm using Golang as the second language

Comment: no problem, just though I'd throw that in there.  If the communications already were designed to go from python to python you could just call the processing-heavy code directly from the python scripts.  You wouldn't even have to change the import statements for the ones still written in python.

Comment: Writing C via the FFI is a far harder task than just hacking along in Go -- the fact that @pupizoid is using ZeroMQ means that there's no need to be focused on interpreter-local objects.

Comment: In reference to your example code, `zmq.REP` blocks on `recv` until it receives a request.  Are you sure there's messages available for the client?

Comment: @tristan, yes, I'm sure. I've run client code for several times, and later to make everything clear, I've tried to request server with python client, and it worked out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programming languages are able to communicate with each other -- yes, you can write a server in Go and a client in Python and have them communicate with each other.

If you're trying to communicate using raw sockets, look at the documentation for your desired languages and make sure that the serialized data match in structure.

e.g. You could decide on a struct and implement your payload in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) or code and then match that structure in [Go](https://godoc.org/github.com/joshlf/gopack) (there may be a better/stdlib way in Go; I'm not very experienced in this language).  The potential maintenance and implementation headache in worrying about these details is why people use higher-level protocols -- exactly a good use case for ZeroMQ.

If you're using a message queue as the backbone of your operation, simply use that as the shared protocol.  If your Python code can speak with ZeroMQ, then it's doing its job correctly -- there's no need for your Go code to know it's speaking to Python.

In this case, your new [Go server would bind to ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:go), your [Python client would bind to ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python), and your two heterogenous languages need to know nothing about each other.

Comment: I thought so, but in practice that doesn't work even with simple examples, which I've added to my question.

Comment: Well, I've tried to run everything conversely, and to my happiness, it finally worked out when python client connected to go server and delivered a message. It turns out that I did something wrong from the beginning, so that all thanks to your answer, which added me confidence in the obvious things :)

Comment: @pupizoid Oh, glad to hear it -- that also means I can stop setting up a Go environment on this machine :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit late but I found this post while I am trying to find a golang-to-python 0mq implementation.

In my golang code, I have just changed `zmq` to **`zmq4`** and everything worked for me:

```
import (
    zmq4 "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
)

func main() {

    ctx, _ := zmq4.NewContext()
    sock, _ := ctx.NewSocket(zmq4.REQ)

    sock.Connect("tcp://localhost:57000")
    sock.Send("simple message", 0)
}
```

Comment: Hi, as far as I know the "shortcut" to imported module doesn't really matter. And as I found earlier there was something wrong with my system setup and in the end all worked out. But anyway thanks for reply!